# Place div on bottom of page with dynamic content

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I want to place a footer div at the bottom of the page. The problem is, I have a dynamic content, so I can not work with "position: fixed;".

The page looks something like this:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="navbar">...</div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

When I click a link in the navbar, another content is loaded with ajax and written in the "content" div. So the height of the page changes. The footer must always be at the bottom of the screen, when there is no overflow of the content and must be at the bottom of the page, when the content gets too long. How can I realize this?

Comment: Check CSS Sticky Footer: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: That does not work at all. The footer still is underneath the content.

Comment: There is a problem with the "min-height" attribute. I set the height of the body to 100%. But when I set the min-height of the wrapper to 100%, nothing happens.

Comment: You must mean "That does not work for me". Check the site and resize your screen, does the footer stick to the bottom? So will it stick to the bottom as your content resizes? It should! Show us what you tried instead of saying it doesn't work.

Comment: I put the footer div outside of the container div and added the push div just like the example. Then I really copy/pasted the whole css code. The only difference are the names of the div elements. Here check it out for yourself: http://the-djinns.de/#home. The footer is cleary not at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You forgot the height: 100% on html

Comment: Okay, looks better now. Thanks. But the page is still a bit too long. I set the html and body height to 96% instead. Now it's perfect.

Comment: Alright, I'm gonna add this as an answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to check out "CSS Sticky Footer": https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/
That's the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

with dynamic content, you can always use this:

[**sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way**](http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/)

always helps!! :)

==================================================================================

**EDIT**

[**see this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6AWW4/)

**CSS**

```
html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body > #container {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 3em;
    margin-top: -3em;
    background-color:grey;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">My Dynamic Footer</div>
```

**Note** : In the fiddle, un-comment the text to see the footer stretching the height after a dynmic height content!!

**Reference** :  [Refer here](http://www.lwis.net/journal/2008/02/08/pure-css-sticky-footer/)

Comment: Not for me. Does not have any effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use this Structure:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:150px;
```

and set

```
position:Relative
```

for its parent.

Comment: This makes the footer stick in the middle of the page.

Comment: no its not correct,close your firebug and then check again,are you set position relative to its parent?

Comment: when the content overflows everything is shown correct. but if the content is shorter than the screen, the footer sticks in the middle of the page. i checked and everything is just like you suggested.

Comment: you must to set min-height to your content wrapper like your main Div,when you set min-height:700px; your footer position is bottem and when your content height more than 700px, browser automaticaly change.